# rad window is not opening

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a radwindow that is being opened by a view column from a rad grid. but the thing is that nothing is happening , the window is not even opening!!!

i want to passe 2 parameters to the RadWindow.

this is the javascript im using:

```
 function ShowEditForm(IdVoiture, IdType, rowIndex) {
            var grid = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>");

            var rowControl = grid.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[rowIndex].get_element(); grid.get_masterTableView().selectItem(rowControl, true);              
            window.radopen("ViewForm.aspx?IdVoiture=" + IdVoiture, "&IdType=" + IdType,"UserListDialog");
            return false;         
         }
```

and this is my column code from the radGrid:

```
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateViewColumn">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="ViewLink" runat="server" Text="View"></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

this is the code behind:

```
 Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridItemEventArgs)


    If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
        Dim editLink As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("ViewLink"), HyperLink)
        editLink.Attributes("href") = "#"
        editLink.Attributes("onclick") = [String].Format("return ShowEditForm2('{0}','{1}');", e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("DepIDVoit"), 4, e.Item.ItemIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

i'm not able to locate my error and i tried to do the same as other examples it is still not working please help!!!

****Mark that my code is in an .ascx page contained inside an multipage in a .aspx page , and the javascript is in the .aspx page i dont know if that makes any differencs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out what was missing. my javascript code was correct but my page was missing a RadWindowManager